# NER: Relate extracted entity to single real world concept

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am processing plain text documents and identifying entities like college/university names present in the document. Some times these names are written in different formats but they refer to a single college/university name.

Example:

Jawaharlal Nehru Technological University Hyderabad

J.N.T.U Hyderabad

JNTU Hyderabad

JNTU-H

Jawaharlal Nehru Technological University (JNTU) Hyderabad

All the above names refer to same college name.

How can we relate all these names to a single college/university names?
(I am looking for some kind of web service or something like Google search because if i search for any of those names it returns same college link.)

Answer (score 0):

This task is named "Entity Linking". Some systems are dedicated to this, in most cases by leveraging Wikipedia (in particular redirects which give possible mentions for entities), such as [Babelfy](http://babelfy.org/) or [DBpedia Spotlight](http://dbpedia-spotlight.github.io/demo/).

Those service rely on data to link mentions to unique identifiers: if they have possible mentions for your entities, it should probably work in most cases (but for those that are to ambiguous). But in many cases their lexicon are not sufficient and you'll probably face unknown entities or mentions. In that case, you'll have to build your own system by using an existing framework and provide it with relevant database of entities and their mentions. Acronyms could be automatically generated from their full names.